# Scanning Windows for Rootkits using Linux

Tags: antivirus, malware, rootkit

I know of ClamAV for viruses, but is there an option for scanning AND getting rid of "rootkits" from Windows from inside Linux i.e. Live boot USB? Also spyware and malware scanning would be nice too. Considering on getting into working on and fixing computers (residential) as a side deal. But want to do things as Linux based as possible.

In order to do that business, will need to get back into the "Windows" swing of things. But hopefully will be good chance to swing people to the Freedom side of things. Which is why I want as much Linux tools as possible.

Comment: In my experience, most of the linux tools are inadequate to repair windows. Most of the time the only option with the linux tools is to delete suspect files and there are lots of false positives , so you need to be careful. As far as I know, the linux tools can not edit or repair the windows registry. I advise you use the windows tools or seek professional assistance.

Comment: Thank you, I've been using a combination of "Combo Fix" and Malawarebytes in Safe Mode, and Then installing the free Avast Anti-Virus as it's boot-up scan does a really good job, and because it has a Free Remote Desktop Feature (but I have no Windows machines myself so not too useful)

I just wanted to use really Freedom Based Software to do this, but with Microsoft locking things even tighter, this will get harder, not easier. :-(